# Conversion from one form of XML to another form of XML

Tags: java, sax

I am trying to convert an XML file of one particular format i.e. with with one set of tags to another set of tags and when I am printing the data between the tags in the new file, it is getting repeated 100s of times. I am getting the new tags and everything but the data is getting repeated many times. For example: If the sentence is "Hello", Hello is getting repeated many times.

I am using SAX parser to parse the old XML file and Node class using appendChild to put the contents into the new file.

Kindly help me with this! I'll provide the code.
Thank you!

Comment: so, please kindly provide the code

Comment: I couldn't have said it better: provide the code

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using XSLT rather than a XML parser to transform XML.

Having said that, there is most likely something wrong with your SAX callbacks to cause something like that to happen.  I can't be more specific without seeing your actual code.